# C++ pointer passed by reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

The following code won't compile:

```
void function(const char*& i){
   // do something
}

int main() {
    char a = 'a';
    char *p = &a;
    function(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain to me why?
What is the code doing? the code in the main function is passing a normal pointer to char to a pointer to a constant char.

As far as I know, as long as the passed pointer does not get violated in the function, the call should be allowed.

the address and value of a normal pointer to char may be modified, so such a pointer cannot be violated if passed by reference to a function whose sole argument is a pointer to a constant char because such a pointer can only modify its address, and that does not violate the restrictions of a normal pointer to char.

Edit:
The reason it does not compile is because when char* is converted to const char*, it results in an rvalue of type const char*. in C++, a non-const reference cannot be attached to an rvalue.
So the solution is simply to make the reference constant by adding const to give the argument the type constant pointer ... to a constant.

```
void function(const char* const& i){
   // do something
}

int main() {
    char a = 'a';
    char *p = &a;
    function(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some will say that "a pointer to a constant should only  store the address of a constant character", well that makes sense, but in the code above, I just need to remove to ampersand symbol to enable the code to compile. so pass by value would work fine. in addition, if the argument is const char* const& or char*const&, the code also compiles fine.

Comment: your function expects a pointer of type `const char*` but you are passing it a non-const `char*`. This means that `p` should be of type `const char*`.

Comment: It would help if you actually posted the compiler error.

Comment: "cannot convert argument 1 from 'char *' to 'const char *&'" is the error message from CLion, but my question is why?

Comment: A reference of type 'const char*&' cannot be initialised with a value of type 'char*', but a reference of type "const char* const&" can be initialised with a value of type "char *" . my question is why?

Comment: You said it in your first comment: *"a pointer to a constant should only store the address of a constant character"*.

Comment: "Some will say...

Comment: Fyi, the reference in your case attaches to `const char*`, which is *not* `char*` . Similar reason a `const char **` is not compatible when passing a `char **` . You would experience the same problem if the function parameter were `const char**` and you had passed `&p` from `main`. Also note that tossing the reference out produces legitimate outcome, since `char*` is implicitly value-convertible to `const char*`.

Comment: I have been experimenting with all the combinations between types of pointers and this is the only one I cannot understand. I would like someone to give me the why. or is it something that should just be taken like that. similar reason. what is that reason? if the argument was "char * const & " or" const char * const&" or "char*&", it would work, which makes perfect sense to me. I just do not understand why this does not work.

Comment: q.v.: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#constptrptr-conversion  The `const char*& i` tells the compiler "I may modify this pass-by-reference argument", so the code disallows passing a *temporary* to the function.  Change the parameter to `const char* const& i` which tells the compiler "I promise not to modify the pass-by-reference parameter" which can bind to a temporary just fine.

Answer (score 1):

what you're doing is no much different from

```
const char* function(){
   return "const char*";
}

int main() {
    char *p = function(); // not compile
}
```

It's obviously wrong to have a non-const `char*` point to a constant

---

re comment: *it is obviously very different. the `const char*&` means "I will not modify the value of a pointer to char passed to me"*

**NO** it does not means that ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bnb6Ye5E8))

```
void function(const char*& i){
   i = "const char*"; // compiles fine
}

int main() {
    const char *p;
    function(p);
}
```

Comment: hi. thanks for the answer. it is obviously very different. the "const char*&" means "I will not modify the value of a pointer to char passed to me". That means essentially that const char*& would not violate a normal pointer to char in the funciton. if you pass the char* by value in the code above, it works. but if you pass by reference, it does not work. why?

Comment: @justastar no it does not means that, see updated answer.

Comment: @justastar so? if you can pass a `char* p`, you now have `p` point to const string literal. which is  **obviously wrong**. How this not answer your question?

Comment: have a good day and thank you for your time.